# function.name returns empty string if the function is added to an object by property

Tags: javascript, function, object

Consider this code example:

```js
let test = {
    test: function(){}
  }

test.print = function(){}

console.log(test.print.name) // Outputs ""
console.log(test.test.name) // Outputs "test"
console.log(test) // Outputs { test: function(){}, print: function(){} }
```

Why is there a difference between the `name` properties of these two functions?

Comment: One performs a [NamedEvaluation](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-namedevaluation), the other does not.

Comment: when you assign a function to a key on an existing object, function doesn't gets a name. This was a design decision by the TC39 because it was considered too much of an information leak.

Comment: thanks a lot, but is there a way to get the name of a function declared in the following way, or will it be without a name anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The technical explanation: NamedEvaluation

The specification tells you:

```js
({ test: function(){} })
```

> #### [13.2.5.5 Runtime Semantics: PropertyDefinitionEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation)
>
> *PropertyDefinition* : *PropertyName* `:` *AssignmentExpression*
>
> 1. Let *propKey* be the result of evaluating `PropertyName`.
> 2. […]
> 3. If [IsAnonymousFunctionDefinition](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isanonymousfunctiondefinition)(*AssignmentExpression*) is true, then
>
>    1. Let *propValue* be ? [NamedEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-namedevaluation) of *AssignmentExpression* with argument `propKey`.
> 4. Else,
>
>    1. Let *exprValueRef* be the result of evaluating *AssignmentExpression*.
>    2. Let *propValue* be ? [GetValue](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getvalue)(*exprValueRef*).
> 5. […]

In step 3, *IsAnonymousFunctionDefinition* of the expression `function(){}` returns **true**, because it [is a function definition](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-isfunctiondefinition), and it [lacks a BindingIdentifier](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-hasname).

Therefore, a [NamedEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-namedevaluation) is performed: the function is created with `"test"` as the value of the `name` property.

---

```js
test.print = function(){};
```

> #### [13.15.2 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation)
>
> *AssignmentExpression* : *LeftHandSideExpression* `=` *AssignmentExpression*
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LeftHandSideExpression*.
> 2. […]
> 3. If [IsAnonymousFunctionDefinition](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isanonymousfunctiondefinition)(*AssignmentExpression*) and [IsIdentifierRef](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-isidentifierref) of *LeftHandSideExpression* are both **true**, then
>
>    1. Let *rval* be [NamedEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-namedevaluation) of *AssignmentExpression* with argument *lref*.[[ReferencedName]].
> 4. Else,
>
>    1. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *AssignmentExpression*.
>    2. Let *rval* be ? [GetValue](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getvalue)(*rref*).
> 5. Perform ? [PutValue](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-putvalue)(*lref*, *rval*).
> 6. […]

In step 3,

- *IsAnonymousFunctionDefinition* of the expression `function(){}` returns **true**, just like it does in the other snippet,
- but *IsIdentifierRef* of the expression `test.print` returns **false**: it’s a *MemberExpression*, not an *Identifier*.

Therefore, step 4, the “Else” case, is taken and no [NamedEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-namedevaluation) is performed.

---

### The rationale: security

The only difference is the additional *IsIdentifierRef* step, which is also the [key to finding](https://google.com/search?q=TC39+%22IsIdentifierRef%22) the [rationale](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/name-anonymous-functions-on-property-assignments) (on esdiscuss.org):

[2015-07-25 14:22:59 UTC](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/name-anonymous-functions-on-property-assignments#content-0) *a.d.bergi at web.de* writes:

> [If] a function (or class) definition is assigned to a property of an object, [the function automatically being given the name of the target identifier] doesn’t happen:
>
> ```js
> var o = {};
>
> o.someProperty = function() { … };
> o.otherProperty = class { … };
> ```
>
> I don’t see any reason for not doing this. [It] just seems to be advantageous and make the language more consistent. I’m quite sure it wouldn’t break any compatibility.

This is one of the replies:

[2015-07-26 19:48:15 UTC](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/name-anonymous-functions-on-property-assignments#content-2) *Allen Wirfs-Brock* writes (emphasis mine):

> [T]he **possibility that the property key is a symbol** is a primary reason that this expression form **does not set the `name` property**.
>
> There may also be **security concerns**. The `name` property **potentially leaks** via the function object the name of the variable it is initially assigned to. But there isn’t much someone could do with a local variable name, outside of the originating function. But a leaked property name potentially carries a greater capability.

Allen goes on, [2015-07-26 20:33:07 UTC](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/name-anonymous-functions-on-property-assignments#content-7):

> TC39 reached consensus on automatically assigning the `name` property for expression forms like:
>
> *Identifier* `=` *FunctionExpression*
>
> and so it is part of ES2015. We **did not have consensus on doing the same** for:
>
> *MemberExpression* `.` *IdentifierName* `=` *FunctionExpression*
>
> or
>
> *MemberExpression* `[` *IdentifierName* `]` `=` *FunctionExpression*
>
> so it is not part of ES2015. There were **various objections** that would have to be overcome before we could adopt that.

Another comment, [2016-12-13 09:03:40 UTC](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/name-anonymous-functions-on-property-assignments#content-13) by T.J. Crowder states that it’s unclear what those “various objections” were.
They link to the [original proposal](https://web.archive.org/web/20160915164848/wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:function_name_property) (archived from wiki.ecmascript.org, 2016-09-15, last available version) which *does* list your expected behavior in an example:

> ```js
> obj.property = function(){}; // "property"
> ```

But keep in mind that this was still an unfinished proposal back then.
When the proposal got accepted into the specification, it seems that it underwent some changes, but the proposal article didn’t get changed to reflect these changes.

This thread mentions certain TC39 meeting notes where this is discussed, but no link is provided.
Allen is claiming that this kind of information leak is the reason why TC39 couldn’t reach a consensus on allowing this behavior.
They mention [2017-01-28 15:46:54 UTC](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/name-anonymous-functions-on-property-assignments#content-20):

> [F]or `cache[getUserSecret(user)] = function(){};` it would leak the secret user info as the value of `name`.

Even though, as T.J. Crowder mentions [2017-01-28 16:11:26 UTC](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/name-anonymous-functions-on-property-assignments#content-21), the same thing is possible with:

> ```js
> cache = {
>   [getUserSecret(user)]: function() {}
> };
> ```

### There isn’t an easy workaround with anonymous functions

*“Is there a way to get the name of a function declared [like `test.print = function(){};`]?”*

Not really.
You could iterate through the object’s entries and find candidates for key names where the value matches the function.
But if the function is referenced by another key name, you may get multiple results.
Also, this gets more complicated if the key is a [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#symbols_as_function_names).

```js
const test = {
    test: function(){}
  }

test.print = function(){};
test.someOtherAliasForPrint = test.print;
test[Symbol("someSymbolForPrint")] = test.print;

console.log(
  "Possible function names:",
  Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(test))
    .filter(([key, {
      value
    }]) => value === test.print)
    .map(([key]) => key)
);
console.log(
  "Possible function symbols:",
  Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(test)
    .filter((symbol) => test[symbol] === test.print)
    .map((symbol) => String(symbol)) // Or `.map(({description}) => description)`
);
```

Your best bet is to define the method like this:

```js
test.print = function print(){};
```

However, consider using [method syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#method_definitions) instead:

```js
({
  test(){},
  print(){}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

How you are defining print is using **anonymous** functions and accessing their name property will return ''. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#anonymous_function_expression)

If you still want to make the code work you can change your code like this :

```
 test.print = function print() {

    }
```